# Nuget autoupdate in website

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

For a customer we are trying to build a webb application that they can build patches (new versions) and their customers can by them self by a click in the app update.

I have made some minor experioments on nuget before and had this as an reference:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx

unfortunatly some of the nuget packages installed and used in this project where to new and not compatible with the nuget package of autoupdate 0.2.1 uses NuGet.Core 1.3.20419.9005.

So i took the autoupdate code and upgraded nuget to 2.5 and fixed all new issues with the new nuget core (changes in functions/parameters etc.).

Now it works so far as i can se wich package is installed, and i can see that there is a new version on the remote server. Howerver when i try to upgrade the local package to the version on the server i get an error:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.

this is where the code goes wrong:

```
public IEnumerable<string> UpdatePackage(IPackage package)
    {
        return this.PerformLoggedAction(delegate
        {
            bool updateDependencies = true;
            bool allowPrereleaseVersions = true;
            this._projectManager.UpdatePackageReference(package.Id, package.Version, updateDependencies, allowPrereleaseVersions);
        });
    }

    [EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
   NuGet.IProjectSystem.get_ProjectName() +0
   NuGet.ProjectManager.UpdatePackageReference(String packageId, Func`1 resolvePackage, Boolean updateDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean targetVersionSetExplicitly) +1014
   NuGet.ProjectManager.UpdatePackageReference(String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Boolean updateDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) +233
```

the package param is the package i want to upgrade to.

In my web app i got the folder \App_Data\packages that holds my .nupkg file that is installed. On my remote folder i got all installed packages + my new version package.

I dont understand what the entrypoint is and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of time googling and code inspect and re-engineering code, it looks like the problem is in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration wich is only compatible with NuGet.Core (≥ 1.6.2 && < 1.7). Re-engineered the **WebProjectSystem** class and now it kinda works.

```
string webRepositoryDirectory = WebProjectManager.GetWebRepositoryDirectory(siteRoot);
        IPackageRepository sourceRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(remoteSource);
        IPackagePathResolver pathResolver = new DefaultPackagePathResolver(webRepositoryDirectory);
        IPackageRepository localRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(webRepositoryDirectory);
        IProjectSystem project = new WebProjectSystem(siteRoot);
        this._projectManager = new ProjectManager(sourceRepository, pathResolver, project, localRepository);
```

The UpdatePackage methods also dosent seam to do the job, only updates references or something. When uppgrading to a new version of my package (eg. deploy new images or html files) seams like i need to use the following method instead:

```
public IEnumerable<string> InstallPackage(IPackage package)
    {
        return this.PerformLoggedAction(delegate
        {
            bool ignoreDependencies = false;
            bool allowPrereleaseVersions = true;
            this._projectManager.AddPackageReference(package.Id, package.Version, ignoreDependencies, allowPrereleaseVersions);
        });
    }
```

this goes through all my files in the package and seams to replace them.
however i got some weird issues with some files get 0 bytes after upgrade (only binary dll files, what i have seen so far).

Need some more research on this.

Comment: Did you ever get any better results for this? I did update the WPS class as well, from Haacked's updated post (source now on GitHub - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx) but still get the EntryPointNotFoundException.